# Gitlab API: How to make a project at root / namespace?

Tags: git, gitlab

we have a gitlab setup at our office, and I want to be able to make projects at it by command line I have been using the http curl to do so, but it always makes project on my name, rather than making it on root [/] namespace

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 5xgss2ZZNcaWp4Hd" --data "name=testcurl9" http://192.168.1.91/gitlab/api/v3/projects
```

I am really out of clue as gitlabhq api doesn't seem to have any option for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The global/root namespace was removed in GitLab 6.0. A project can either be in a member's namespace or in a group's namespace.